# Incorrect text colouring on earned bounties in the Reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Looking at [my Reputation tab](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot?tab=reputation) for yesterday when I earned a bounty and the text of it is green, same as normal positive reputation events, and it has the blue bounty background.

[image: Reputation tab showing incorrect colouring]

I believe it should have white text like the accepts and how it used to be. In fact they still show with white text and the blue background on SO.

[image: Reputation tab on S?O showing correct colouring]

**Can this be fixed so it has the correct colouring again?** It is hard to read at the moment for the best of us but I imagine some colour blind people might not be able to read it at all.

Comment: After posting I found this was reported on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328559/345161) and is currently `[status-review]`. It was also reported on [SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385529/4631427) but looking through my old SO profile the bounty text is the correct colouring so looks like it was fixed there.

Comment: Confirming that this was fixed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387558/8157789. Let me know if you're still seeing issues and we'll re-open. Thank you for reporting.